# Domain name registrar for rare ccTLDs

Tags: domain-name-system

We've a number of rarer country codes to transfer, namely:
.asia
.bo
.cl
.com.mx
.com.ve
.es
.hu
.kr
.lu
.me
.my
.no
.pe
.pt
.si
.sk

I've not found a registrar that handles even half of those, and would rather avoid using more than one, though perhaps that'll be necessary.

So, any recommendations for registrars that'll handle them?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

ICANN and IANA are your friends.

For the generic TLDs, ICANN has a [list of approved registrars.](http://www.icann.org/en/registrars/accredited-list.html)  For the country codes, I don't think there's any way to find a registrar that deals with all the ones you want, you'll have to go through [IANAs list of domain authorities](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/) and see who the registrars are.

Looking at some of the ccTLDs you listed, [Safenames in the UK](http://www.safenames.net/) seems to cover lots of domains.

Answer (score 0):

try [eurodns.com](http://eurodns.com), they seem to sell [most of domains](http://www.eurodns.com/prices/domain-names-price-list/) you are looking for.

i have no links to eurodns, although i've been buying domains from them for last few years and i do not have any reason to complain.

Answer (score 0):

I use [MarkMonitor](http://www.markmonitor.com/) for all 1400 or so of my domains and have had a fairly positive experience with them. I've not yet run across a TLD that they couldn't get for me...